# Can this SPARQL update be simplified?

Tags: sparql, rdf

The update is used to move one item (*source*) in an RDF sequence after another (*target*) and recalculate the sequence indices accordingly. Regardless whether the source originally appears before or after target, it has to be placed immediately after the target in the result. You can picture this as a drag and drop operation.

An example of a sequence looks like this:

```
<https://linkeddatahub.com/demo/northwind-traders/>
    a      <https://w3id.org/atomgraph/linkeddatahub/default#Root> ;
    rdf:_1 <https://linkeddatahub.com/demo/northwind-traders/#page-header> ;
    rdf:_2 <https://linkeddatahub.com/demo/northwind-traders/#top-selling-products> ;
    rdf:_3 <https://linkeddatahub.com/demo/northwind-traders/#top-manager-header> ;
    rdf:_4 <https://linkeddatahub.com/demo/northwind-traders/#top-manager> ;
    rdf:_5 <https://linkeddatahub.com/demo/northwind-traders/#select-children> .
```

SPARQL update:

```
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  ldh:  <https://w3id.org/atomgraph/linkeddatahub#>
PREFIX  ac:   <https://w3id.org/atomgraph/client#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

DELETE {
  $this ?sourceSeq $sourceContent .
  $this ?targetSeq $targetContent .
  $this ?seq ?content .
}
INSERT {
  $this ?newSourceSeq $sourceContent .
  $this ?newTargetSeq $targetContent .
  $this ?newSeq ?content .
}
WHERE
  { $this  ?sourceSeq  $sourceContent
    BIND(xsd:integer(substr(str(?sourceSeq), 45)) AS ?sourceIndex)
    $this  ?targetSeq  $targetContent
    BIND(xsd:integer(substr(str(?targetSeq), 45)) AS ?targetIndex)
    BIND(if(( ?sourceIndex < ?targetIndex ), ( ?targetIndex - 1 ), ?targetIndex) AS ?newTargetIndex)
    BIND(if(( ?sourceIndex < ?targetIndex ), ?targetIndex, ( ?targetIndex + 1 )) AS ?newSourceIndex)
    BIND(IRI(concat(str(rdf:), "_", str(?newSourceIndex))) AS ?newSourceSeq)
    BIND(IRI(concat(str(rdf:), "_", str(?newTargetIndex))) AS ?newTargetSeq)
    OPTIONAL
      {   { $this  ?sourceSeq  $sourceContent
            BIND(xsd:integer(substr(str(?sourceSeq), 45)) AS ?sourceIndex)
            $this  ?targetSeq  $targetContent
            BIND(xsd:integer(substr(str(?targetSeq), 45)) AS ?targetIndex)
            $this  ?seq  ?content
            FILTER strstarts(str(?seq), str(rdf:_))
            BIND(xsd:integer(substr(str(?seq), 45)) AS ?index)
            FILTER ( ( ?index > ?sourceIndex ) && ( ?index < ?targetIndex ) )
            BIND(( ?index - 1 ) AS ?newIndex)
          }
        UNION
          { $this  ?sourceSeq  $sourceContent
            BIND(xsd:integer(substr(str(?sourceSeq), 45)) AS ?sourceIndex)
            $this  ?targetSeq  $targetContent
            BIND(xsd:integer(substr(str(?targetSeq), 45)) AS ?targetIndex)
            $this  ?seq  ?content
            FILTER strstarts(str(?seq), str(rdf:_))
            BIND(xsd:integer(substr(str(?seq), 45)) AS ?index)
            FILTER ( ( ?index < ?sourceIndex ) && ( ?index > ?targetIndex ) )
            BIND(( ?index + 1 ) AS ?newIndex)
          }
        BIND(IRI(concat(str(rdf:), "_", str(?newIndex))) AS ?newSeq)
      }
  }
```

I think it does what I need it to do, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it more compact that I'm not seeing right now.

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously possible to replace `UNIION` with `||`:

```sql
BIND (?index > ?sourceIndex  &&  ?index < ?targetIndex AS ?isBetweenSourceAndTarget) 
BIND (?index < ?sourceIndex  &&  ?index > ?targetIndex AS ?isBetweenTargetAndSource) 
FILTER (?isBetweenSourceAndTarget || ?isBetweenTargetAndSource)
BIND (?index + if(?isBetweenSourceAndTarget, -1, +1) AS ?newIndex)
    
BIND (IRI(concat(str(rdf:), "_", str(?newIndex))) AS ?newSeq)
```

But perhaps it is simpler to recalculate *all* `rdf:_n`:

```sql
DELETE { $this ?seq ?content }
INSERT { $this ?newSeq ?content }

WHERE {
   SELECT $this ?seq ?content (IRI(concat(str(rdf:_), str(count(*)))) AS ?newSeq) {
 
      $this  ?sourceSeq  $sourceContent .
      BIND (xsd:decimal(strafter(str(?sourceSeq), '_')) AS $sourceIndex)
      $this  ?targetSeq  $targetContent
      BIND (xsd:decimal(strafter(str(?targetSeq), '_')) AS $targetIndex)

      $this  ?seq  ?content . FILTER strstarts(str(?seq), str(rdf:_))
      BIND (xsd:decimal(strafter(str(?seq), '_')) AS ?oldIndex)
      BIND (IF(?content = $sourceContent, $targetIndex + 0.5, ?oldIndex) AS ?newIndex)
  
      $this  ?seq_  ?content_ . FILTER strstarts(str(?seq_), str(rdf:_))
      BIND (xsd:decimal(strafter(str(?seq_), '_')) AS ?oldIndex_)
      BIND (IF(?content_ = $sourceContent, $targetIndex + 0.5, ?oldIndex_) AS ?newIndex_)

      FILTER (?newIndex >= ?newIndex_)
   }
   GROUP BY $this ?seq ?content
}
```